# Use Mcmcpack for latent variable

Tags: r, bayesian, mcmc

I am using mcmcfactanal from MCMCpack in R to generate posterior distribution to generate a latent factor variable. I have two questions.

1. Do I need to set store.scores to TRUE to get the necessary distribution for creating latent variable?
2. I ran following sample code

```
  library(MCMCpack)
  data(swiss)
  posterior <- MCMCfactanal(~Agriculture+Examination+Education+Catholic+Infant.Mortality, 
                             factors=2,  
                             lambda.constraints=list(Examination=list(1,"+"), 
                                                     Examination=list(2,"-"), 
                                                     Education=c(2,0),     
                                                     Infant.Mortality=c(1,0)),  
                             verbose=0, store.scores=TRUE, a0=1, b0=0.15, 
                             data=swiss, burnin=5000, mcmc=50000, thin=20)
```

But I could not find where the scores stores from the option `store.scores= TRUE`.

Comment: A quick look at `dimnames(posterior)` suggests they are stored in the output matrix with column names starting with `phi_`