# Using MCMCpack for latent variable and extracting latent scores from mcmc object

Tags: r, bayesian, mcmc

I'm using functions `MCMCordfactanal()` and `MCMCirtKd()` from R package **MCMCpack** to generate a posterior distribution and create a latent factor variable.

I could check latent scores using `summary()` and `dimnames()`, but I still wouldn't know how to extract those values and make them into a single latent variable.

I ran following code:

```r
fact_posterior <- MCMCordfactanal(~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4, data=vdem, 
    factors=1, lambda.constraints=list(x1=list(1, "+")), burnin=5000, 
    mcmc=50000, thin=100, verbose=500, L0= 0.5, store.lambda=TRUE, 
    store.scores=TRUE, tune=1.2)

irt_posterior <- MCMCirtKd(t(vdem), dimensions=1, burnin=5000, mcmc=50000, 
    thin=10, B0=.25, store.item=TRUE, item.constraints=list("1"=list(2, "-")))
```

I'm expecting to get a single latent variable from the `mcmc` object generated by `MCMCordfactanal()` and `MCMCirtKd()`

Comment: Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75390164/use-mcmcpack-for-latent-variable#comment133026313_75390164) recent question, it seems as if they are stored in the variables with names starting `phi`. The posteriors means can be extracted from the summary with `st <- summary(posterior)$statistics;  st[grep("phi", rownames(st)), "Mean" ] ` or directly from the samples with `colMeans(posterior[, grep("phi", colnames(posterior))]))`

Comment: the last code worked! thanks a lot :)